# String subtype error when calling function in flutter

Tags: flutter

i am having a problem calling a function that pass a string as parameter and return a string as value.  it is a custom validator function and that function will be pass to another class.  i am getting error message such as:
type 'String' is not a subtype of type '(String) ==> 'String'

below is my code

this is the code for calling the function

```
 Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, bottom: 5.0, left: 15.0, right: 15.0),
              child: CustomTextField(textInputType:TextInputType.number,
                textController: amountController,
                labelText:'Income Amount for testing',
                validator: textFieldValidator('Income'))
            ),
```

this is the function code

```
  Function(String) textFieldValidator = (String textFieldName){
    if( textFieldName == 'Income')
      return 'errorIncomeAmount';

    return null;
  };
```

i also change the function to look like below but still same error

```
   textFieldValidator  (String textFieldName){
    if( textFieldName == 'Income')
      return 'errorIncomeAmount';

    return null;
  }
```

i am not sure why i am getting error  - type 'String' is not a subtype of type '(String) ==> 'String'

all i am doing is calling the function by passing a string, compare the string inside the function to another string and return a string.  then pass that function as a validator to a textformfield.

can someone help solve this issue so i dont get error? thanks in advance

Comment: You need to pass function validator: textFieldValidator but not the result of function as in code validator: textFieldValidator('Income')

Comment: hi Sergey, i am not clear. so you are saying i cannot pass the parameter and do comparison inside the function?  how do i fix it so that i can compare string and then return a string?

Comment: validator accept callback i.e. function that will be called after you enter data in CustomTextField. Pass to validator textFieldValidator without parentheses. When function called it accept as parameter current value, then you decide if it correct.